# Difference between "angualar.module" and "module" when unit-testing Angular

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs

What is the difference between `angual.module('app')` and `module('app')`?

Here is the simple service and unit test in question:

**Service**

```
(function () {
    "use strict"

    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.service('CustomerService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            getById: function (customerId) {
                return $http.get('/Customer/' + customerId);
            }
        }
    }]);
}());
```

**Test**

```
describe('Customer Service', function () {
    var $rootScope,
        $httpBackend,
        service,
        customerId = 1;

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.module('app', ['ngMock']);

        inject(function ($injector) {
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            $httpBackend.whenGET('/Customer/' + customerId).respond({ id: customerId, firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow' });

            service = $injector.get('CustomerService');
        });
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should get customer by id', function () {
        var customer;

        service.getById(1).then(function (response) {
            customer = response.data;
        });

        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(customer.firstName).toBe('Sam');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`module` in the unit test framework refers to the mock `angular.mock.module` method (which is attached to window as a convenience). `angular.module` is the method that `angular.mock.module` mocks.